# Having trouble understanding why my JS isnt working

Tags: javascript

Nothing is happening for me when I run this code.

```
var myarray = [2,2,2];

for ( var i = 0 ; i < myarray.length ; i++ ) {
  total = total + myarray[i];
}
alert("The total is " + total);
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Comment: It seems you're looking for something like [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try defining total outside of the loop first.

```
var myarray = [2, 2, 2];
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
  total += myarray[i];
}
alert(`The total is ${total}!`);
```

Something was happening, but you likely couldn't see it. Try to open the developer console in your browser if you're using one to run this, you'll see the error being generated.

Comment: Wooooow. Thanks. haha

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your variable and initialise it:

```
var total =0;
for ( var i = 0 ; i < myarray.length ; i++ ) {
  total = total + myarray[i];
}
alert("The total is " + total);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer something so simple. lol

Comment: Vote if it helped (:

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to solve it is using reduce as below, cheers! ;)

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];


var total = arr.reduce((acum, current) => acum + current);

console.log(total);
```